# How can I take a screen shot of entire Screen on regular intervals using Adobe flex and action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How can I take screen shot  of Entire on Screen regular intervals (random between 2 to 5 minutes) without click event using Adobe flex and action script. Currently I am doing it with the `Mouse_Up` Event and then calling the timer and then saving each image with different name

```
 package
{
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.utils.Timer;



    public class Grabber extends Sprite
    {
        private var stageCover:Sprite;
        private var captureRect:Sprite;
        private var sx:Number;
        private var sy:Number;
        private var np:NativeProcess;
        private var npi:NativeProcessStartupInfo;

        public function Grabber()
        {
            super();
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            stageCover = new Sprite();
            stageCover.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.01);
            stageCover.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, Capabilities.screenResolutionX, Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
            addChild(stageCover);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

            captureRect = new Sprite();
            captureRect.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF);
            addChild(captureRect);

            np = new NativeProcess();
            npi = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        }


        private function onTimerComplete( event:TimerEvent):void
        {


            captureRect.graphics.clear();
            var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            args.push("-l");
            sx =0;
            args.push(sx.toString());
            args.push("-t");
            sy = 0  ;       
            args.push(sy.toString());
            args.push("-r");
            var a:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
            args.push(a.toString());
            args.push("-b");
            var b:Number= Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
            args.push(b.toString());


            args.push("-out");
            args.push(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/grab.jpeg");
            npi.arguments = args;
            npi.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("GrabberCommand.exe");
            np.start(npi);

        }

        private function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
        {


        var timer:Timer=new Timer( 10*1000*Math.random(),1 );
            timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerComplete );
            timer.start();



        }

    }
}
```

**XML Properties are**

```
SystemChrome  none 
Transparent  true
SupportedProfiles  extendedDesktop
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually did something like this before.

You will need a `Timer` that calls the following function at intervals (whatever intervals you like):

```
private function captureScreenshots(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var imgEnc:IImageEncoder;
        var screenshotArray:Array = new Array();


        if(myView.encodingCombo.selectedItem == "PNG")
    {
        imgEnc = pngEnc; //private const pngEnc:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    }
    else
    {
        imgEnc = jpgEnc; //private const jpgEnc:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
    }

    var windowsArray:Array = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows;

    for each(var window:NativeWindow in windowsArray)
    {
        if(window && window.stage is IBitmapDrawable)
        {
            var imageSnapshot:ImageSnapshot =  ImageSnapshot.captureImage(window.stage as IBitmapDrawable, 0, imgEnc); 
            screenshotArray.push(imageSnapshot);
        }
    }



    windowsArray = null;
}
```

You can then use a `FileStream` to write them to a directory, but that would be a different question.

Comment: @TheDean I might have made a mistake... I just wanted to take a screenshot of the AIR Windows, but re-read the question, and it seems you want the entire screen.

Comment: Yes I want the screen shot of entire screen even task bar too to check what user have done while working on the assigned Task which can be seen by their Team Admin

Comment: I want the screen shot automatic . not on any mouse event ... regular interval and then screen shot automatic . could you help me ??

Comment: @TheDean I mentioned using a Timer... that is the automatic part. There are loads of examples of Timer and interval counts out there, and they would do exactly what you're looking for

Comment: i have done the screen shot using the mouse event it is giving me result what i want  but now i got stuck at the point how can i do it with the TIMER . i took the screen shot of the entire screen . but implementing it with the timer event is quite tough for a noob like me. i am editing my my question and showing you what i have done

Comment: timer should be a class level variable (member variable). Does the onTimerComplete get called? You should forget about the screen capture for a bit and do some trace()/debugging breakpoints to find if the timer is called properly. Also, the timer should be added in the constructor.

Comment: Yes There Are Errors . 
1. Native process Is already running .
2. Timer issue taking screen shots within seconds not according to TImer specified.